# How to place bubbles for a Bubble Shooter game? AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a Bubble shooter game in ActionScript 3.0 and I'm having trouble placing the bubbles right. It should look something like this:

```
00000000
 00000000
00000000
 00000000
```

but I'm only placing the first and the third row at the moment and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Here is my code so far:

**bubble_mc:** (which is my bubbles, there's 6 different bubbles)

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class bubble_mc extends MovieClip {
        public function bubble_mc(val:uint,row:uint,col:uint) {
            gotoAndStop(val+1);
            name=row+"_"+col;
            x=50+col*36;
            y=40+row*36;
        }

    }

}
```

**Main:**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private const ROT_SPEED:uint=2;
        private const R:uint=18;
        private const D:Number=R*Math.sqrt(3);
        private var bubbleArr:Array=new Array();
        private var cannon:cannon_mc;
        private var bubble:bubble_mc;
        private var left:Boolean=false;
        private var right:Boolean=false;
        private var bubCont:Sprite;
        public function Main() {
            placeContainer();
            placeCannon();
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKUp);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEFrame);
        }
        private function placeCannon():void {
            cannon=new cannon_mc();
            addChild(cannon);
            cannon.y=385.5;
            cannon.x=320;
        }
        private function onKDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37 :
                    left=true;
                    break;
                case 39 :
                    right=true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private function onKUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37 :
                    left=false;
                    break;
                case 39 :
                    right=false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private function onEFrame(e:Event):void {
            if (left) {
                cannon.rotation-=ROT_SPEED;
            }
            if (right) {
                cannon.rotation+=ROT_SPEED;
            }
        }
        private function placeContainer():void {
            bubCont=new Sprite();
            addChild(bubCont);
            bubCont.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xffffff,1);
            for (var i:uint=0; i<4; i++) {
                if (i%2==0) {
                    for (var j:uint=0; j<15; j++) {
                        bubbleArr[i]=new Array();
                        bubbleArr[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
                        bubble = new bubble_mc(bubbleArr[i][j],i,j);
                        bubCont.addChild(bubble);
                    }
                } else {
                        if (j<14) {
                            bubbleArr[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
                            bubble = new bubble_mc(bubbleArr[i][j],i,j);
                            bubble.x=68+i*36;
                            bubCont.addChild(bubble);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved it! In case someone has the same problem, here is the code:

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and then accept your own answer.  That way it shows up as answered and accepted for others searching for as3 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it! In case someone has the same problem, here is the code i solved it with! (The changes I have made to x-coordinates doesnh't matter..)

**bubble_mc:**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class bubble_mc extends MovieClip {
        public function bubble_mc(val:uint,row:uint,col:uint) {
            gotoAndStop(val+1);
            name=row+"_"+col;
            x=59+col*36;
            y=40+row*36;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private const ROT_SPEED:uint=2;
        private const R:uint=18;
        private const D:Number=R*Math.sqrt(3);
        private var bubbleArr:Array=new Array();
        private var cannon:cannon_mc;
        private var bubble:bubble_mc;
        private var left:Boolean=false;
        private var right:Boolean=false;
        private var bubCont:Sprite;
        public function Main() {
            placeContainer();
            placeCannon();
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKUp);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEFrame);
        }
        private function placeCannon():void {
            cannon=new cannon_mc();
            addChild(cannon);
            cannon.y=385.5;
            cannon.x=320;
        }
        private function onKDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37 :
                    left=true;
                    break;
                case 39 :
                    right=true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private function onKUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37 :
                    left=false;
                    break;
                case 39 :
                    right=false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private function onEFrame(e:Event):void {
            if (left) {
                cannon.rotation-=ROT_SPEED;
            }
            if (right) {
                cannon.rotation+=ROT_SPEED;
            }
        }
        private function placeContainer():void {
            var iRow:Boolean=false;
            bubCont=new Sprite();
            addChild(bubCont);
            bubCont.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xffffff,1);
            for (var i:uint=0; i<4; i++) {
                if (! iRow) {
                    for (var j:uint=0; j<15; j++) {
                        bubbleArr[i]=new Array();
                        bubbleArr[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
                        bubble = new bubble_mc(bubbleArr[i][j],i,j);
                        bubCont.addChild(bubble);
                        iRow=true;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (j=0; j<15; j++) {
                        bubbleArr[i]=new Array();
                        bubbleArr[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
                        bubble = new bubble_mc(bubbleArr[i][j],i,j);
                        bubble.x=77+j*36;
                        bubCont.addChild(bubble);
                        iRow=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```